# Emitting application level metrics in node js

Tags: node.js, metrics

I want to emit metrics from my node application to monitor how frequently a certain branch of code is reached. For example, I am interested in knowing how many times a service call didn't return the expected response. Also I want to be able to emit for each service call the time it took etc.

I am expecting I will be using a client in the code that will emit metrics to a server and then I will be able to view the metrics in a dashboard on the server. I am more interested in open source solutions that I can host on my own infrastructure.

Please note, I am not interested in system metrics here such as CPU, memory usage etc.

Comment: https://swaggerstats.io/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implement pervasive logging and then use something like [Elasticsearch + Kibana](https://www.elastic.co/kibana) to display them in a dashboard.

There are other metric dashboard systems such as Grafana, Graphite, Tableu etc. A lot of them send metrics which are numbers associated with tags such as counting function calls, CPU load etc. The main reason I like the Kibana solution is that it is not based on metrics but instead extracts metrics from your log files.

The only thing you really need to do with your code is make sure your logs are timestamped.

Google for Kibana or "ELK stack" (ELK stands for Elasticsearch + Logstash + Kibana) for how to set this up. The first time I set it up took me just a few hours to get results.

Node has several loggers that can be configured to send log events to ELK. In addition the Logstash (or the modern "Beats") part of ELK can ingest any log file and parse them with regexp to forward data to Elasticsearch so you do not need to modify your software.

The ELK solution can be configured simply or you can spend literally weeks tuning your data parsing and graphs to get more insights - it is very flexible and how you use it is up to you.

#### Metrics vs Logs (opinion):

What you want is of course the metrics. But metrics alone doesn't say much. What you are ultimately after is being able to analyse your system for debugging and optimisation. This is where logging has an advantage.

With a solution that extracts metrics from logs like Kibana you have another layer to deep-dive into behind the metrics. You can query it to find what events caused the metrics. This is not easy to do on a running system because you would normally have to simulate inputs to your system to get similar metrics to figure out what is happening. But with Kibana you can analyse historical events that already happened instead!

Here's an old screenshot of a Kibana set-up I did a few years back to monitor a web service (including all emails it receives):

[image: Kibana screenshot]

Note the screenshot above - apart from the graphs and metrics I extract from my system I also display parsed logs at the bottom of the dashboard so I get near real-time view of what is happening. This is the email received dashboard which we used to monitor things like subscriptions, complaints, click-through rates etc.

Comment: Note that the open source version of Kibana does not have a login feature but you can easily implement login by putting it behind Apache or Nginx and configure your web server to do old school basic auth.